# Initializing set with comparator in C++

Tags: c++, set, comparator

I encountered the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

int main() {

   auto comp = [](int x, int y){return (x > y); };

   std::set<int, decltype(comp)> inversed({1,2,3,4,5}, comp);
   for ( auto i = inversed.begin(); i != inversed.end(); ++i ) {
      std::cout << *i << std::endl;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

The code prints "5 4 3 2 1", i.e initial set in inversed order. Can anybody explain why? How comparator influences initialization of the set?

Thanks,
Kostya

Comment: Flip the sign in your comparator?

Answer (score 5):

An [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) uses a comparator to determine the order of elements. The default semantics for a comparator is "less", which means that if running a comparator on two values (A,B) returns `true`, then A should be placed before B.

In your case, the comparator does the opposite (returns `true` if A is  "greater" than B), that's why bigger elements appear in front of the smaller ones.

Answer (score 3):

When defining `comp`, you are defining the **order function** for your set. For your set, two elements will be ordered if its order function will be fulfilled.

So, being `std::set` an *ordered container*, you get that result, i.e. `inversed` store its elements sorted, but the order is *descending* because it's the order defined by `comp`.